# How to cache Google Satellite images?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, satellite

Is it possible to download all tiles at all available zoom levels for an entire large city from Google Satellite view layer and if so how to do that through use of available open source software? I want to download all such tiles and serve them from my own geoserver and for offline viewing and testing.

This is for internal use and testing and not for publishing over the wider internet.

Comment: I would suggest that you review the Google Earth terms of service and try to reframe this question such that you show how you are compliant with those terms.

Comment: Bradhards question edited.

Comment: That would likely still be a violation of 10.4.c(ii) and 10.4.d. Basically, you can't legally do this, AFAICT.